# Game not installling with error code 80073cf9

Tags: apps

While I was installing smash bandits racing it was not installed and shown this code `80073cf9` help me to fix the problem. I downloaded the game from appx4fun.com and tried to install at store in install local apps but it not installing showing that code `80073cf9`.

Comment: Are the region and location set correctly on your phone?

Comment: Is appx4fun a legitimate site?

Answer (score 1):

**Most preferred solution**

Install the app through Windows store instead of installing via offline. The app you mentioned is available in windows store. You can find it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Smash-Bandits-Racing/9NBLGGH16PLL).

*Store link : https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Smash-Bandits-Racing/9NBLGGH16PLL*

However if you still wanted to install through an offline file see the following steps.

---

Similar problems were reported in [Microsoft community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps/80073cf9/da1829dc-7f5e-4a5e-8cdf-ab64e68d6d60) and [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880453/5407188). From these conversations I have listed some steps to solve this problem.

---

**Steps**

1. Invert any changes made to your region recently.
2. Make sure that your storage location for apps is set to phone memory.
3. Make sure date and time of your phone is set correctly.
4. Set your region and Time zone to same country.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your phone, and try again! these errors appear sometimes. Check if the date and time are correct!